# Jade, how to escape hash character?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have the following line in my Jade template:

```
img(src='#{similarArtist.image[0].#text}')
```

Do not ask me why Last.fm guys decided it was a good idea to use a name starting with hash in JSON document, but this is what I am dealing with.

It seems the 2nd hash sign trips up Jade. Maybe it expects two braces afterwards? I have tried prepending it with a backslash character (traditionally an escape operator) but that did not help.

So what can I do in this case? I really need to access that `#text` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` is not allowed in dot notation but you can use array notation for that. You can simply do:

```
img(src='#{similarArtist.image[0]['#text']}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very beautiful solution but it works:

```
!= '<img src=' + similarArtist.image[0]['#text'] + '>'
```