# Escaping text in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping, pug

So this question has been asked before, but I keep getting errors in my output.

So, escaping text in jade.

I have this markup

```
.left
  :markdown
  each post in site.posts
    a.post(href='#' + post.title)
      h2= post.title
```

The a tag will anchor scroll to the corresponding post. Now I want to escape that the `post.title` inside of the href so that the spaces are removed.

Now I've seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926247/nodejs-jade-escape-markup)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486190/jade-how-to-escape-hash-character), but both of them throw errors when I try to compile everything.

The custom filter throws and error saying `unknown filter` and the second one throws this error

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Potentially unhandled rejection [152] SyntaxError: /Users/mhartington/Github Repos/ionic-node-faq/views/index.jade:14
    12|       :markdown
    13|       each post in site.posts
  > 14|         a.post(href='#' + #{post.title})
    15|           h2= post.title
    16|     .right
    17|       each post in site.posts
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove spaces from the `post.title` with [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
a.post(href='#' + post.title.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
```

You may also use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) other special characters for inclusion in URLs:

```
a.post(href='#' + encodeURIComponent(post.title.replace(/\s+/g, '')))
```

---

The error with using `#{...}` is because it's a Jade syntax that's expected only within [plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/). And, the [values of attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/) are parsed as JavaScript, which doesn't support such syntax.

If you're concerned about HTML-encoding the attribute's value, Jade will already handle that as needed.

```
- post = { title: 'Foo>Bar' }
a(href='#' + post.title)
```

```
<a href="#Foo&gt;Bar"></a>
```

Comment: Was looking for something a bit more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926247/nodejs-jade-escape-markup

But this works for me. Thanks a lot!